Using SQLConnection Without SQLConnection NUGET
Create a new Visual C# .NET Windows application.
Add below usings:
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

Code like:
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
'SqlConnection' is underlined as error (could not be found...)
If you add SQL NUGET Package it is OK, no error.
Is it possible to code this without NUGET?
I want to use System.Data.SQLClient without installing NUGET Package.

What Framework are you using .NET Framework 4.x or .NET Core ?

@SuryatejaKONDLA, it's pretty much a given that they're targeting .NET 6+ but reading instructions written for .NET Framework. Not saying that you shouldn't ask but I'd bet a lot of money that that is the case.

Project is using .Net Core 8 Framework, thanks

For the record, it's just .NET 8. They used the ".NET Core" name officially up to version 3.1 but, because .NET Framework was discontinued at version 4.8.x, .NET Core skipped version 4.x and they went to .NET 5 as it was touted as a merger of .NET Core and .NET Framework. Functionally, that is largely the case but it was written on top of the .NET Core codebase with .NET Framework-specific functionality reimplemented. People will use ".NET Core" to generally refer to anything not .NET Framework but, from version 5, specific versions use ".NET" rather than ".NET Core".

yes, .NET 8.0 only

I have removed the  tag since this isn't related to the SQL language. Instead you can add a tag for the dbms used. (Perhaps ?)

As with any type, in order to use the SqlConnection class, you must reference the assembly that it is declared in. If you're targeting .NET Framework then you can simply add a reference to System.Data.dll, although many project templates do so by default.
If you are targeting .NET Core, including .NET 5 or later, then only certain assemblies are referenced by default and any other references are generally added by installing the appropriate NuGet package. You are probably targeting .NET 6 or later so installing the System.Data.SqlClient or, preferably, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package is the way you're supposed to reference the appropriate assembly to use the SqlConnection class.
Stop trying to avoid doing things the right way just because you're reading a tutorial that was written for an older version of .NET than you're targeting. Otherwise, if you want to target .NET Framework, create a project that actually does so, rather than targeting .NET (Core).

not possible to use .NET Framework anymore, so had to use NUGET, thanks.

@BirYazilim, there are many assemblies that you added by reference before that are now added as NuGet packages. It's the way it's supposed to be so don't fight it.

@BirYazilim, if an answer resolves your issue, please click the check mark to accept it. This enables everyone to see that your problem has been resolved without their having to open and read the question and comments.
